# Using Oracle 19C driver to 11G database

Tags: oracle11g, oracle19c

Is there any harm or issue using the Oracle 19C JDBC [ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar] drivers to work with 11G database? We are in mid of migration but due to internal complex mechanism there will be case during which this scenario can happen in the Prod environment.

Comment: Were you able to use ojdbc8-19.3.0.0 with 11G database successfully? We're currently forced to do the same approach (with Oracle version being 11.2.0.4). For now it seems to be working properly, but I'm wondering if there are any corner cases which could fail.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [JDBC FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html). Latest JDBC drivers are backward compatible but, if the support period ends then, we cannot guarantee support for the older versions.
You can check out the [Lifetime Support Policy](https://www.oracle.com/us/support/library/lifetime-support-technology-069183.pdf) for Oracle Database. The Oracle Database 11.2.0.4 extended support ended on Dec 2020.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at oracle doc for more info:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/JDBC-getting-started.html#GUID-926E5324-D89A-4A00-B1AE-975C1089F0EA

[image]

I think it can work but not sure how compatible it is. Also depend on your java version. if u want to integration between java version 8+ and Oracle database version 11G.

In the best, it should be **ojdbc6.jar** with JDK 6, JDK 7, JDK 8 or **ojdbc5.jar** with JDK 5 for 11G database.